# Why the dual function $\theta(u)$ is wrong?

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

**Attempt** Define $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ and $g(x)=-x_1-x_2+4\le 0$

a) Clearly $g(\overline x)\le 0$ and $f(\overline x)=8,$ thus $\overline x$ is optimal solution.

b)

- We have that the Lagrangian dual problem is given by $\max \theta (u), s.t. u\ge 0,$ where $\theta (u)= \inf \{f(x)+u^tg(x)\}$.
- The dual function is given by $\theta(u)=\inf\{x_1^2+x_2^2+u(-x_1-x_2+4):x_1,x_2\in X\}=-3u$ if $u\ge 0$

if $u<0$, then $\theta(u)=3u$.

However it does not match with the expected dual function $\theta(u)=-u^2/2=4u$ :(

- If we consider this dual function $\theta(u)=-u^2/2-4u$ then $\max \theta(u)=8$ when $u=-4$. Hence does not exist duality gap.

Could someone please tell me why I get a different dual function?

What am I doing wrong? I just split the infimum and each of them gave $-u/2$. Hence the total infimum is $-u+4u=3u$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider how to minimize $x_1^2+x_2^2+u(-x_1-x_2+4)$ where $u \ge 0$ is fixed.

If we differentiate wrt $x_i$, we obtain

$$2x_i-u=0$$

Hence $$x_i=\frac{u}2 \ge 0$$

Hence the optimal value is

$$2\left( \frac{u}2\right)^2+u\left(-u+4 \right)$$

I think you left out the quadratic part and I can't tell where does $-u$ comes from.

Comment: Isn't just about to calculate the infimum of $\theta$? I don't see where the quadratic part came form. Could you explain please?

Comment: we are trying to minimize $x_1^2+x_2^2+u(-x_1-x_2+4)$ subject to nonnegative constraint right? isn't the objective function a quadratic function?

Comment: :) yes , I still don't get it, the quadratic part $2\left( \frac{u}2\right)^2+u\left(-u+4 \right)$?, there's an example in the book, but it does not really explain that part, it just give the function

Comment: I just substitute $x_1=x_2=\frac{u}2$ into the quadratic function.

Comment: got it, although it's not about to minimize but maximize the Lagrangian dual problem

Comment: yes, we will maximize the dual function, but in finding the dual function, we find the infimum.

Comment: ok,, thank you.

Comment: I think the book has a typo $-4u$, your answer gives $4u$